# Add images in start of mp3 video Android

Tags: android, video, mp3

I have recorded video from my android app and now i want to add the logo in the beginning of the video. Any way to decode the video and add frames in start of it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add frames to the video you need to reencode the whole video. The most powerful library for doing such things is [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) but it is not pure java so you need to compile your own build and probably use JNI  or run it via android's (linux's) command line using java wrapper like [this one](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java). So you can run command like this in android's command line from your app:

```
  ffmpeg -i INPUT -map 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy OUTPUT // reencoding  video to h.264 codec
```

Another way of doing what you want is probably using new [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) stuf but its's available since API 16 (and some usefull class since even API 18) and the documentation and web examples are rather poor.